# SWIG + JNI: One method work rest don't

Tags: java, java-native-interface, swig

Okay this is random. I have a small test for JNI and swig I am working on. 
Which semi works. Because one method works they others do not. when they are called I get java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError. 
The method working is printHello(std::string), if have tried to add extern to the methods, no luck. I have tried to have the methods right after the includes, can anyone explain why it does not, my code is below.

interface file (demo.i):

```
%module demo
%{
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include "demo.hpp"

%}

%include "std_string.i"

int addx(int x, int y);
void printHello(std::string);
void printHelloWorld(std::string);
void printHelloW(std::string);
```

My header file (demo.hpp)

```
void printHello(std::string);
void printHelloW(std::string);
void printHelloWorld(std::string);
int addx(int x, int y);
```

My cpp code implementation (demo.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "demo.hpp"

void printHelloW(std::string name){
  std::cout << "Hello: "<< name << "\n";
}

void printHello(std::string name){
  std::cout << "Hello: "<< name << "\n";
}




void printHelloWorld(std::string){
  std::cout << "Hello World \n";
}

int addx(int x, int y){
  return x + y;
}
```

And of course my java file:

```
public class Test{
    static{
    System.loadLibrary("demo");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

    demo.printHello("Lars");

    demo.printHello("Jeppe");
    demo.printHelloW("Jeppe");
    demo.printHelloWorld("JOHN");
    demo.addx(2, 4);


    /*john j = new john();
      System.out.println(j.add(1,1) + "");*/

    }
}
```

Output from java Test

```
java Test
Hello: Lars
Hello: Jeppe
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: demoJNI.printHelloW(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at demoJNI.printHelloW(Native Method)
    at demo.printHelloW(demo.java:24)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer I need to run

```
 $export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

After creating the .so file